# Access headers sent from webview in angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, webview, angular-ui-router

I am loading an angular application in a webview as shown below

```
WebView.loadUrl(String url, Map<String, String> additionalHttpHeaders)
```

I maintain a state for this in the angular application and show the content accordingly.Is there a way i can read the headers sent fromt he webview in my angular application ?
state in my angular code

```
$stateProvider.state('external', {
    abstract: true,
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
});

$stateProvider.state('external.details', {
    url: '/details?vendor&id&title',
    templateUrl: '/partials/details',
    controller: 'DetailsCtrl',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use Javascript to access request headers (it's by design, so not an angularjs issue).

The only way to do this is for the server to read the request headers and then pass them on to the angular application in some form.

Why not use the URL query string optional parameters if you want to pass values to the ui-router?

Comment: Thanks @stefan for clarifying.  I want to maintain log in session. I cant send the session id in url query string. Also what if i have 5 params or more. The URL would be too long in that case.

Comment: @koundinya did yu solve yur problem. I'm in this exact situation where I have to send Access token in webview url as query string but it doesnt work due to long string. how to go about it? plz help, if yu can.